# How to load Kendo UI widgets faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI widgets such as the line chart, grid and date pickers.  I love the product however I'm noticing a latency issue when the page loads.

For example with the grid; I first see a standard HTML table load, then a second later or so it's redrawn with the kendo grid.

The same goes for my datetime pickers, radio buttons etc.  This is an example of all the css and scripts I'm using in the order in a layout page for a dashboard I'm working on... I'm not a big fan of bundling, therefore I leave the scripts as is in the page.  I know that if you bundle (if it works...) you gain a slight performance with the threading(?) but I always seem to have issues with the bundler so I leave them in the page.  Is there a sequence to loading these scripts so that you don't see the redrawing of the elements as a user?

Top of Page

```
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/css/kendo/kendo.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/fonts/fontello/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="~/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="~/plugins/iCheck-1.x/skins/square/square.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Bottom of Page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<!-- Isotope javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<!-- Owl carousel javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<!-- Appear javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/jquery.appear.js"></script>

<!-- Sharrre javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/jquery.sharrre.js"></script>

<!-- Count To javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<!-- Parallax javascript -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>

<!-- Knob -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>

<!-- Contact form -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<!-- SmoothScroll javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/jquery.browser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/plugins/SmoothScroll.js"></script>

<!-- Initialization of Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/template.js"></script>

<script src="~/plugins/iCheck-1.x/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/jszip.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Look into using gulp to bundle and minimize your javascript files that will speed up performance quite a bit. You could also put the kendo javascript files in the head of the document and that will cause it to attempt to download the files prior to rendering the page. What's happening is that your page renders before the javascript is downloaded and executed, you can get around that by making sure your js files are loaded first. And then you can put your kendo setup code in the body.

Comment: @Jdsfighter - thanks!  This is an asp.net mvc5 app, would using the bundler be similar to using gulp?

Comment: The bundler isn't as efficient if I recall, and with the newer versions of .Net and VS they've actually moved away from the bundler and are using gulp in place of it. With VS2015 you have native gulp, grunt, and bower support. This means you can create builds that automatically download, compile, bundle, and minimize your dependencies on project build. It will even copy them to their appropriate folders.

Answer (score 1):

Script optimization is one thing. Use css minification and bundling like you do with your Javascript using `@Styles.Render()`. It is mandatory in production environment (if you don't use external minification).

The other thing is Kendo always works this way; first create element and then convert it to the widget.

If you creating widgets in the `document.ready` event all content of the site has to be loaded (including html and  elements) before a widget will be created. Reducing the size of the page content will improve it's load time but you will still have this effect if the user has a slow network connection.

So the first thing you should do is to hide element which you will convert to the widget by setting its display to none. Kendo should show widget like it always does. In asp version it may be a little it harder but you can try hide element container and show it after some widget event.

Second thing is that you can include the code of the widgets that you are using in your project instead of whole kendo.all.min.js. You can find more information here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need (and here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-requirejs).

And the last thing: You can also consider to use CDN (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/cdn-service) especially if you creating site available via internet or your own "intranet CDN" if you are using the same javascripts in few of your projects.

Comment: Appreciate the response!  I ended up taking JDS's advice and put both the scripts and css in the head.  Its a slightly slower response 400 ms but the redrawing UX is now gone!  Secondly, I ended up using the bundle.config file for both the scripts and css which helped with response time.  Its LOB app so it doesn't need to be top notch, therefore these two changes did the trick.  I think if it was a product I'd go a bit further per your suggestion but there's trade off of time invested vs. acceptance being an LOB.  Thanks for the info though!